# Parameterized table name in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to parameterized the table name, so my select can be "Dynamic" in Pandas

My objectives is that , I wanted to create bunch of csv from all the table in my schema.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
# Some other example server values are
# server = 'localhost\sqlexpress' # for a named instance
# server = 'myserver,port' # to specify an alternate port
server = 'DESKTOP\SQLEXPRESS' 
database = 'AdventureWorks2019' 
username = 'sa' 
password = 'password'  
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
# select 26 rows from SQL table to insert in dataframe.
query = "select t.name as table_name from sys.tables t where schema_name(t.schema_id) = 'Person' order by table_name"
df = pd.read_sql(query, cnxn)
print(df)
```

That's how I connect to the SQL Server and i wanted to get all table name from "Person" schema.

```
param=df['table_name'].iloc[0]
query = "select * from {param}"
df = pd.read_sql(query, cnxn)
```

But now i tried to read the tablename, it's not possible.
Because if i have 1000s tables, it would take too long and repetitive tasks to create the csv.

Sorry if my code looks not good, I'm currently still learning python and pandas

##UPDATE

So this is what i made with for loop to create txt files

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    param=row["table_name"]
    query = f"select * from Person.{param}"
    df = pd.read_sql(query, cnxn)
    filepath="C:\Users\imbea\Desktop\test"+{param}+".txt"
    df.to_csv(filepath, index=None, sep='|', mode='a')
```

I got an error of

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

What i was trying to do with my new cell of code, to concate the path with the table name, and with file format of txt

Comment: if you do not need all the data from tables you can use `limit 1` or `limit 10` in your query

Comment: @ArtyomAkselrod I do actually wanted to do all of the tables from my query that list all tables in schema Person, still stuck with the filepath

Comment: so what is the current question? `unicode error`? or the reading of 1000s tables?